# How do you stop scrolling to top when grid store is reloaded - take 2

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have an app that uses ExtJS 3.3.0. It uses an EditorGridPanel in which after the store is reloaded - I would like it to preserve the scroll position of the grid rather than sending it back up to the top.

Since it's an earlier version of ExtJS - this does not work.

```
viewConfig: {
   preserveScrollOnRefresh: true
}
```

I thought I had found a solution per Zeke's suggestion to use a scrollTo function like so:

```
//Save position
var top = grid.getView().scrollergetScroll().top;

//Restore position
grid.getView().scroller.scrollTo('top',top);
```

This works great - except that after it's done reloading it goes right back up to the top.  Basically this would be a perfect solution if only I didn't need preserve the cursor position after reloading the store.

```
grid().getStore().reload({
    callback: function (response) {
        //Works at this point
        grid.getView().scroller.scrollTo('top',top);
    }
}

//However the cursor pops right back up to the top after popping out of 
//reload() block
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little kludgy - maybe the best strategy is just not to use older versions of ExtJS - but this seems to work okay.

Basically just declare some global variables that can be seen from anywhere in the file - one is a flag to indicate that the event that triggers the reload has occured (rowClicked), and one to represent the last known position of the scrollbar

```
var rowClicked = false;
var prevScrollPosition = -1;
```

When the event occurs that will trigger the re-load - set the global variable rowClicked to true

```
rowclick: function(grid, rowIndex, event) {
    rowClicked = true;
```

Then in the listeners of the grid use the rowClicked variable to determine when to re-position the scrollbar.

```
listeners : {                 
    bodyscroll: function(sl, st) {
        if (rowClicked) {          
            getScenarioLineOrderNumbersGrid().getView().scroller.scrollTo('top',prevScrollPosition);
            rowClicked = false;
        }
        prevScrollPosition = st;                      
    }
```

Kludgy - but it works.